# Prove that $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ , $f(x) = \|x\|^2$ is differentiable.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

The question is the same as the title. All I could churn out was that if the gradient at x was $\nabla f(x)$ then $$\langle\nabla f(x),x\rangle = 2\|x\|^2 .$$ I was also wondering whether this can be generalised from $\mathbb{R^2}$ to $\mathbb{R^n}$

**Edit**
The norm can be any norm

Comment: As you can see, there is a lot of confusion around your question: do you suppose your "any norm" to come from a scalar product?

Comment: True in any inner product space. Definitely false with "any norm".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may write, as $||h|| \to 0$,
$$
\begin{align}
f(x+h)-f(x)&=||x+h||^2-||x||^2
\\&=\langle x+h,x+h \rangle-\langle x,x \rangle
\\&=\langle x,h \rangle+\langle h,x \rangle+\langle h,h \rangle
\\&=\langle x,h \rangle+\langle h,x \rangle+||h||^2
\\&=\langle x,h \rangle+\langle h,x \rangle+o(||h||)
\end{align}
$$ or

> $$
> f(x+\color{blue}{h})-f(x)=\langle 2x,\color{blue}{h} \rangle+o(||\color{blue}{h}||).
> $$

Comment: sorry for confusion, the norm can be any norm.

Comment: Any two norms are equivalent on a f.d. vector space.

Comment: @AndréS. but does differentiability of one implies the diff. of other? i thought it applied only on convergences

Comment: Differentiability is a question of the existence of a limit and convergence. But if two norms are equivalent they define the same notion of convergence. If you find this unclear just take two norms $p$ and $q$ with $cp \leq q \leq Cp$ for some $c,C  > 0$ and try to prove that $f$ is differentiable w.r.t. $p$ iff $f$ is differentiable w.r.t. $q$.

Comment: @AndréS. Um, still I don't get it , yes I get the $||.||$ in $||f(x+h) - f(x) - Df(x)h||$ can be any norm but how does that allow me to change say $f(x) = ||x||^2_2$ to $f(x) = ||x||^2_9$ ?

Answer (score 9):

This is false for general norms. For instance, the $1$-norm of $x=(x_1,x_2)$ is expressed as $$\|x\|_1=|x_1|+|x_2|.$$ From this we obtain $$f(x)=\|x\|_1^2=|x_1|^2+2|x_1||x_2|+|x_2|^2=x_1^2+2|x_1||x_2|+x_2^2.$$ This immediately implies that $f$ is not everywhere differentiable. We can show this by defining $$g(x)=f(x)-x_1^2-x_2^2$$ and noting that $f$ is differentiable if and only if $g$ is, since they differ by a differentiable function. However, we may easily see that $g$ fails to be differentiable at $(0,\frac12)$. To show this, let $$h(x_1)=g(x_1,\tfrac12)=|x_1|,$$ and note that $h$ is just the absolute value function. But the absolute value function obviously fails to be differentiable at $0$, so $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1}(0,\tfrac12)=h'(0)$$ cannot exist.

Comment: I think the OP is thinking of a norm induced by an inner product.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: In his edit, the OP says "any norm". It's true, though, that he also uses a scalar product in his question.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: I initially also thought so. But in a comment below Olivier Oloa's answer, the OP explicitly mentions the $9$-norm.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff  Well the thing is that I misread the question in a book , it was mentioned prove or disprove  , i overlooked the "disprove" part hence  I got stuck , I had a solution for norms induced my inner product space. And I'm now facing a moral dilemma about who should  I give the bounty as all the answers are quite good.

Comment: @LucyferZedd re "moral dilemma": "any norm" represents a requirement in your problem (i.e. something you cannot deviate from), "prove" does not in my opinion. Hence, this seems the only answer that actually makes sense with the inputs. If you think that both have the same "strength" as requirements, the only really good answer would be that the exercise is wrong as you can't keep both and again, this seems the most applicable answer as the other ones demonstrate that the differentiability applies with inner products, not that it might not apply with other definitions of a norm.

Answer (score 5):

Abstract proof good for any inner product space $E$: The function is composition of of two differentiable functions: the diagonal $E\longrightarrow E\times E$ and the scalar product (bilinear and continuous).

Answer (score 3):

I explain using linear algebra. The vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{R}^n$ and the vector function $f(\mathbf{x})=\|\mathbf{x} \|_{p}^2$ are defined. Then, the gradient of $f(\mathbf{x})$ is shown below.

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla f(\mathbf{x})=& \cfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}\biggl( \sum _{k=1}^{n} x_{k}^p \biggr)^{\frac{2}{p}} \\
=& 2 \biggl( \sum _{k=1}^{n} x_{k}^p \biggr)^{\frac{2-p}{p}} x_{i}^{p-1} \\
=& 2\|\mathbf{x} \|_{p}^{2-p}  \ \mathbf{x}^{p-1}
\end{align}
$$

These inner product can be described using vectors.

$$
\begin{align}
\langle \nabla f(\mathbf{x}), \mathbf{x} \rangle =& 2\|\mathbf{x} \|_{p}^{2-p}  \ (\mathbf{x}^{\text{T}} \mathbf{x}^{p-1}) \\
=& 2 \biggl( \sum _{k=1}^{n} x_{k}^p \biggr)^{\frac{2-p}{p}} \biggl( \sum _{k=1}^{n} x_{k}^p \biggr) \\
=& 2\|\mathbf{x} \|_{p}^{2-p} \|\mathbf{x} \|_{p}^{p}
\end{align}
$$

Particularly, $p=2$ that gives the Euclidean norm. Therefore, $\nabla f(\mathbf{x})=2 \mathbf{x}$ , $\langle \nabla f(\mathbf{x}), \mathbf{x} \rangle =2 \|\mathbf{x} \|_{2}^{2}$ because $\|\mathbf{x} \|_{2}^{0}=1$. Finally, it can be expressed as follows like your description when $n=1$, $x \in \mathbf{R}$ and $p=2$.

$$\langle \nabla f(x), x \rangle =  2\|x \|^{2}$$